# How to Convert Hex String Into Unsigned Integer Using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, number-formatting

I have some string fields that store hexadecimal representation of unsigned integers in reverse byte order. I'd like to convert it back to integers.

For example the string `deadbeef` must result in number `4022250974`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for normal byte order [here](https://gist.github.com/ChiChou/97a53caa2c0b49c1991e):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  unhex(str, val, weight) AS (
    SELECT 'deadbeef', 0, 1
      UNION ALL
        SELECT 
          substr(str, 1, length(str) - 1),
          val + (instr('0123456789abcdef', substr(str, length(str), 1)) - 1) * weight,
          weight * 16
        FROM unhex WHERE length(str) > 0
  )
  SELECT val FROM unhex order by weight desc limit 1;
```

and I then adapted it to do the same for reverse byte order:

```
WITH RECURSIVE unhex(str, val, weight) AS (
  SELECT 
    'efbeadde', 0, 1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    substr(str, 3), 
    val + (instr('0123456789abcdef', substr(str, 2, 1)) - 1) * weight + (instr('0123456789abcdef', substr(str, 1, 1)) - 1) * weight * 16, 
    weight * 256 
  FROM unhex WHERE length(str) > 0
)
SELECT val FROM unhex order by weight desc limit 1;
```